# show result in listview in android from retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, retrofit

I am trying to show the result of json in listview by using retrofit library the code is correct without any error but it dose not display the result.... if anyone can help me please.

job_vec.php

```js
<?php 

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
  
 
       // $id  = $_GET['id'];  
  require_once('db.php');
  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM  job_entity ";
  
  $r = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);  
  $result = array();
  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
               array_push($result,
               array('Id'=>$row['id'],
      'Title'=>$row['Title'],
      'City'=>$row['City'],
      'Address'=>$row['Address'],
      'Specialization'=>$row['Specialization'],
      
 ));
}
  echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
  
  mysqli_close($connection);
  
 }
 ?>
```

jobAPI.java

```js
public interface jobAPI {
    @GET("job_vec.php")
    public void getJobs(Callback<List<job_entity>> response);
}
```

and the methods to show the result in listview

```js
package com.example.hamdaalissaei.flah.service;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.hamdaalissaei.flah.InterfaceAPI.jobAPI;
import com.example.hamdaalissaei.flah.R;
import com.example.hamdaalissaei.flah.model.job_entity;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;

public class Job_vacancy extends AppCompatActivity  implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.0.120/flah";
    public static final String KEY_Title = "Title";
    public static final String KEY_City = "City";
    public static final String KEY_Address = "Address";
    public static final String KEY_Specialization= "Specialization";
    private ListView listView;
    private List<job_entity> jobs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_vacancy);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        getJobs();
        //Setting onItemClickListener to listview
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    private void getJobs() {
        //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

        //Creating a rest adapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
                .build();

        //Creating an object of our api interface
        jobAPI api = adapter.create(jobAPI.class);

        //Defining the method
        api.getJobs(new retrofit.Callback<List<job_entity>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<job_entity> job_entities, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                //Dismissing the loading progressbar
                loading.dismiss();
                //Storing the data in our list
                jobs = job_entities;


                //Calling a method to show the list
                showList();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    //Our method to show list
    private void showList(){
        //String array to store all the book names
        String[] items = new String[jobs.size()];

        //Traversing through the whole list to get all the names
        for(int i=0; i<jobs.size(); i++){
            //Storing names to string array
            items[i] = jobs.get(i).getTitle();
        }

        //Creating an array adapter for list view
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simple_list,items);

        //Setting adapter to listview
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    //This method will execute on listitem click
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Creating an intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, jobs.class);

        //Getting the requested book from the list
        job_entity job = jobs.get(position);

        //Adding book details to intent
        intent.putExtra(KEY_Title,job.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra(KEY_Address,job.getAddress());
        intent.putExtra(KEY_City,job.getCity());
        intent.putExtra(KEY_Specialization,job.getSpecialization());

        //Starting another activity to show book details
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())
 in your showList() method after your setAdapter().

Comment: I tried to don  notifyDataSetChanged but it still the same problem